# Im getting this error everytime time I want to create a react app:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

The error on the command line:

`npm ERR! cb() never called!`

I ran the command:

`npx create-react-app test`

I also tried running the clean cache command but I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: What node version do you use? It's probably because you're using node 4 or 6. Run `node -v` to see. Better use node 14 if starting a new project.

Comment: Bro I reinstalled node.js yesterday. It is the latest version namely v14.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with --force option?

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

More info refer: https://reactgo.com/npm-err-cb-never-called/

Comment: im using windows OS.

Comment: create-react-app does not work globally  

    npm uninstall -g create-react-app  

    npm install create-react-app  

    create-react-app test

Comment: I uninstalled it globally and reinstalled with `npm i create-react-app`.
its still not working